# Display Contents of a doc file in a textarea in php

Tags: php

I want display the content of doc file in a textarea for my project using PHP as it is means line break, font size etc.
Any code or how to do it. And i will be fetching that doc file from database.

Comment: Just to be sure : by *"doc file"*, you mean a *MS Word* document ? And you want/need to extract its textual content ?

Comment: I want to extract the textual content as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FCKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor). Let  me know if it works